# Developing a web application in Node and using Webpack

Tags: node.js, webpack

I've recently been trying to get my head around moving my web development to Node with React and Webpack.

My question is in regards to what Webpack outputs, would it be a form  I would have to host using Node or could I pack it using Webpack and host it in IIS with no Node dependency?

Comment: webpack will spit out a single javascript file for you, that you can include in an html file and host it however you like.

Comment: @azium perfect, thank you!